# Appropriate method to read shared preference and show/hide controls in android

Tags: android

I would like to execute the following codes-

```
sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences("MyConfig", MODE_PRIVATE);
BrId = sharedPrefs.getInt("BrId", 0); 

if (BrId == 0){
     //Want to show/hide some controls
}
```

What is the best practices to place these? in `onCreate()` or `onStart()` ?

Comment: its depends on your controls.When you change the `BrId` value ?

Comment: If this logic need to populate some UI based on the output during Activity push then the answer is OnCreate()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Condition 1:**

If this logic needs to populate some UI components based on the result and just once before UI rendering , then the answer is `onCreate()`

**Condition 2:**

Whenever the Activity is in foreground and you need some logic , then `onResume()` would prefer. Some other Activity may get pushed on top of this Activity and the value changes due to some business logic. Now its should be in `onResume()`